# How to echo all names of a column in all rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have a remote mysql database and a table with several rows. I want to echo one specific column (attribute) name in all rows.

Below is the php code:

```
<?php
  require "conn.php";
  $command = $_POST['command'];
  $mysql_qry = "select name from college_data;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
  $result_details=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     echo $result_details[0].$result_details[1]." Listall successfully!"; // how to change this line of code
}
  else {
      echo " Listall fails!";
  }
?>
```

More specifically, how to display all the data stored in result_details?

Comment: what's not working; any errors? checking or them? If not... Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: I am new to php and I will read the link thanks.

Comment: Numrows after fetching records not good friend

Comment: oh,ok, i just start learning php .... @devpro

Comment: Appreciate becuase u r using mysqli . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a mess

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     echo $result_details[0].$result_details[1]." Listall successfully!"; // how to change this line of code
}
```

You're fetching only one column. And you're not looping over the result set. Finally, you're fetching an associative array but using numeric keys

So let's clean this up

```
while($result_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $result_details['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

So now we're iterating over your full result set. We're using associative keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code inside the if statement to:

```
foreach($result_details as $row){
  if(is_array($row)){
    foreach($row as $row2){
      echo $row2 . '<br/>';
    }
  }else{
    echo $row . '<br/>';
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your will to help is appreciated, but your answer lacks the details. However, if you specify what you mean by "that line", it will be way better.

Comment: He wants to iterate over the result set. Your code will only iterate the first result